# Is there any online resource which can calculate the equation for the curve with given points?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have several sets of Cartesian coordinates and I am looking for a resource which can generate the formula/equation/function for a curve (or line) which passes through these points.

The first set is:

1,1 - 2,2 - 3,5 - 4,7, - 5,12 - 6,15 - 7,22 - 8,35 - 9,40

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You say "the", as if there is only one. This feels like an instance of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Do you care to elaborate on what your actual goal is?

Comment: @Git Gud There are multiple such collections/sets of points. I am trying to visualize prime number sequences as curves (with each y value being a representation of a prime number). There are more than a dozen such sets, that is why I am looking for a resource to automatically generate formulas for the given values, instead of posting the individual sets here and manually requesting an equation/function for each set.

Answer (score 1):

A search found [OEIS sequence A024702](https://oeis.org/A024702) "a(n) = (prime(n)^2 - 1)/24". For your sequence of values $\,(1,1),\,(2,2),\,(3,5),\dots\,$ The formula is
`a(n) = (prime(n+2)^2-1)/24`. The first few values are:

> 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 15, 22, 35, 40, 57, 70, 77, 92, 117, 145, 155, 187, 210, 222

You are interested [OEIS sequence A000040](https://oeis.org/A000040) "prime numbers" with approximation

```
a(n) = n log n + n log log n + (n/log n)*(log log n - log n - 2) + O( n (log log n)^2/ (log n)^2).
```

which is probably what you are looking for. Consult the OEIS entry for more
information.

Comment: I am indeed plotting different visualizations of prime numbers. I thought this method of visualizing prime sequence is my own idea. Looks like every thought has already been thought, every word already spoken (apology for being poetic here). Many thanks for your answer. As you might have guessed, I am looking for a function which does not use that abominable word "prime" in it, although the curve will quickly deviate from the prime sequence. Anything in the form of x and f(x), without referring to primes.